# Ubuntu 20.04 - How to hide error messages at shutdown

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

My Ubuntu 20.04 displays some error messages at shutdown almost every time.
I want to hide error messages even if there are errors.
Is there way to hide error messages at shutdown on Ubuntu 20.04?

For example, error messages are like the following.(but they are different each time...)

```
[ 1256.107813] uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
[ 1256.107892] uvcvideo 1-1:1.0: reset_resume error -84
[ 1259.253366] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x00170500
[ 1260.265369] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x00170500
[ 1261.227843] reboot: Power down
```

I tried the following command but it didn't work.

`gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt false`

Thanks.

Comment: The simplest way would be to simply "not look". What sort of error messages are you seeing? Something in Gnome? Or is it after the screen goes black and all of the processes are shutting down?

Comment: @Matigo Nice one

Comment: I also have a few of these messages after the screen goes black. I would really want to look at them, but they disappear too fast.

Comment: Are these error or normal messages?

Comment: thanks. I added error messages to my question.
It's displayed after the screen goes black.